# Pandas Multilevel Dataframe Melt

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a following **pivoted** multilevel pandas dataframe structure:

```
       Example1 Example2 Weight Rank Difference
VC                        X Y   X Y
0        ABC      XYZ     1 2   1 2     0
1        PQR      BCD     3 4   3 4     1
```

I want to melt the data frame and get the following structure:

```
 VC Example1 Example2 Weight Rank Difference
 X    ABC       XYZ      1      1      0
 Y    ABC       XYZ      2      2      0
 X    PQR       BCD      3      3      1
 Y    PQR       BCD      4      4      1
```

Code:

```
df = df.pivot_table(index = 
['Example1','Example2'],columns='VC', values=
['Weight','Rank']).reset_index()
df['Difference'] = (df['rank']['X']-df['rank']['Y'])
```

The above code got me to the pivoted frame, the original frame is the output required. So basically, I pivoted a dataframe, now want to melt it to get it back to same structure.

Original Dataframe:

```
 VC Example1 Example2 Weight Rank
 X    ABC       XYZ      1      1  
 Y    ABC       XYZ      2      2    
 X    PQR       BCD      3      3      
 Y    PQR       BCD      4      4
```

Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Can you please add some code to generate these dataframes. It isn't easy for us to copy your data like this. Thanks!

Comment: @COLDSPEED Added some code let me know if it helps.

Comment: @howardroark Can you add the original dataframe/code to produce _that_ so we can then use your code to get the pivoted one?

Comment: @COLDSPEED added the original frame.

Comment: Why not keep original dataframe intact and assign pivot to a different named object? This avoids data wrangling back to original.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, I think you need `stack`, `groupby`, `ffill`:

```
df2.stack(1).groupby(level=0).ffill().dropna().reset_index().drop('level_0', axis=1)
```

Or

```
df.fillna(9999999).stack(1).groupby(level=0).bfill().dropna(‌​).reset_index().drop‌​('level_0', axis=1)
```

## EXAMPLE

df_in

```
  VC Example1 Example2  Weight  Rank
0  X      ABC      XYZ       1     1
1  Y      ABC      XYZ       2     2
2  X      PQR      BCD       3     3
3  Y      PQR      BCD       4     4
```

Your code:

```
df2 = df_in.pivot_table(index = 
['Example1','Example2'],columns='VC', values=
['Weight','Rank']).reset_index()

df2['Difference'] = (df2['Rank']['X']-df2['Rank']['Y'])
```

df2

```
   Example1 Example2 Rank    Weight    Difference
VC                      X  Y      X  Y           
0       ABC      XYZ    1  2      1  2         -1
1       PQR      BCD    3  4      3  4         -1
```

Reshaping:

```
df2.stack(1).groupby(level=0).ffill().dropna().reset_index().drop('level_0', axis=1)
```

Output:

```
  VC  Difference Example1 Example2  Rank  Weight
0  X        -1.0      ABC      XYZ   1.0     1.0
1  Y        -1.0      ABC      XYZ   2.0     2.0
2  X        -1.0      PQR      BCD   3.0     3.0
3  Y        -1.0      PQR      BCD   4.0     4.0
```

Comment: It loses the VC columns records on its entirety

Comment: I get the same result. The problem is dropna(), the values assigned to VC corresponding columns is NA. So using dropna() removes the VC column values

Comment: @howardroark I couldn't replicate your missing VC problem.

Comment: can you try to add values for weight x or y as NaN. This should reproduce the issue. thanks

Comment: you might want to update your answer to support the NaN. This helped me. Adding a long random number for NaN's
  
df.fillna(9999999).stack(1).groupby(level=0).bfill().dropna().reset_index().drop('level_0', axis=1)